# GoogleMaps functionality error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

My app is a geolocation app which silences mobile on entering a geofence.I am able to see googlemaps completely on my debugging apk .however,after downloading it from the playstore,everything works fine except it doesnt show the googlemaps.Instead it shows [image]

Please let me know the problem with that.does the google maps key needs a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well what you have added is the `debug API key` which would support your google map in `debug mode` if your to install your application directly from the Android Studio.

what you need to do is add `release API key` to the project,

There are two different API keys that you need to deal with while working with `Google Maps` one is `debug` and other one is `release` Key.

you need to generate `SHA1` key in release mode and create a API key using this `SHA1` and your project package name, so you can see the `Google map` work in `release` mode,

easiest way to get `SHA1` for release mode is to run your application in release mode and while rendering Google map it would throw you an error along with `SHA1` key with which you need to make `release API key`